# WPF - MVVM Light, Ribbon Control, nested user controls/views and using events between user controls/views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am building a **WPF** application with the aid of **MVVM light** and Unity.
I have a ribbon control in the main form, with one tab without tab category, and two tabs in a tab category. User control 3 includes user control 2 and user control 1.

I would like to make visible the Tab Category and tabs 2 and 3 when I click in user control 2 and make them invisible when click in user control 3 or 1.
I confused a little bit with the event handling in mvvm structure.

I would like to do this properly with the MVVM rules. Could you give me an example or some really helpful directions how to do it?

[Check how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUadK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ribbon or tabs for that matter, should be backed up by a ViewModel, let's say `TabCategoryViewModel` or `Tab2ViewModel` and `Tab3ViewModel`. Inside these ViewModels you inject the `IMessanger` service (of course register it before if not already done) and create a POCO event message, like `SelectedViewMessage`

```
public class SelectedViewMessage 
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your `TabCategoryViewModel` you would register to listen to this message

```
public class TabCategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public readonly IMessanger messageService;

    public TabCategoryViewModel(IMessanger messageService) 
    {
        if(messageService == null) 
        {
             throw ArgumentNullException("messageService");
        }

        this.messageService = messageService;

        this.messageService.Register<GoToPageMessage>(this, OnSelectedViewChanged);
    }

    protected void OnSelectedViewChanged(SelectedViewMessage message) 
    {
         this.IsVisible = message.ViewName == "UserControl2";
    }

    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible 
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set 
        {
            if(isVisible != value) 
            {
                isVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You inject the same `IMessanger` service into your ViewModel you use to Bind your UserControl2 and fire the message via

```
var message = new SelectedViewMessage {
    ViewName = "UserControl2";
};
this.messangerService.Send<SelectedViewMessage>(message);
```

This code can be placed inside a `ViewSelectedCommand` or something similar, and you can use Blend Interactivity Triggers/Actions to bind this to certain events on the View/UserControl

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding event [onPropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever user clicks on the tab and add that property in xaml under Visibility tag. Also look at [Handling UI Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842876/Handling-UI-Controls-Events-in-ViewModel) to understand that mapping in xaml and ti understand event handling from [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776025/MVVM-Event-Routing-to-the-Child-ViewModel) 
Hope it helps.

Comment: He explicitly asked now to solve it via respecting the MVVM pattern. Event Handling violates MVVM pattern. The ViewModel shall be View agnostic